# Android: leave out unused ids in layouts?

Tags: android, xml, layout

i would like to know if it's bad practice when you don't assign an ID to a View, which isn't referenced programmatically, within your xml layout?

Thanks!

Philipp

Comment: No, you shouldn't assign an Id, if you're not programmatically modifying the view or using it in any other way.

Comment: @user3116036 Thank you for accepting the answer, I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a view neither needs to be referenced inside your code nor needs an ID for positioning purposes in the XML layout definition (for the android:layoutAbove/Below etc. properties of child views inside a relative layout), then there is no reason for you to assign an ID to it. I would say generally, it is considered good practice not to assign it, because the IDs you assign will be added to your project's R file, causing unnecessary bloat, however small it may be.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you are not going to use the view from code its better to not give it an I'd.

here are a few reasons:

1. Less xml code.
2. Less options on auto complete with the R.id.